# Creating and apending to object makes not required result

Tags: jquery

I am cloning an element and storing to object. while create the object i adding to `div` and appending to create new element. but i am not get the `loop` decided output.

here is the code :

```
var obj = {el:{}};

var newdiv = $('.div').clone();

var col = $('<div />');

for(i=0;i<10; i++) {
    obj.el['el'+i] == undefined ? obj.el['elm'+i] = {} : null;
    obj.el['el'+i] = newdiv.removeClass('div').addClass('show');
    $(obj.el['el'+i]).appendTo(col);
}

$(col).appendTo('#content');

console.log(col.children());
```

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/hLobnxq5/)

Comment: You're only ever working with one clone. Every iteration of the loop only adds the same clone to the same element, in effect doing nothing. Perhaps you meant to place the `.clone` call inside the loop? http://jsfiddle.net/L6q58tf9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
var $newdiv = $('.div').clone().removeClass('div').addClass('show'),
    $col = $('<div />');

for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
    $newdiv.clone().appendTo($col);

$col.appendTo('#content');

console.log($col.children());
```

In your code, you only cloned `$('.div')` once, so you were always appending the same element. Instead, you should clone the element at each iteration.